# Enable tabbing to next field in Angular x-editable

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

Any idea how to open next field in a table when clicking TAB?

```
<div ng-if="data.external_link !=''">
   <a href="#" editable-text="data.external_link" onbeforesave="updateExternalLInk(data.productID,$data)">
       {{ data.external_link }}
    </a>
<div>
```

This section will open only if I click on it. Also, how do you enable the save when you tab away from this field (if tabbing would actually work at some point)?